# Cookie JavaScript Html

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I want to change cookie from the marked 'object' in JS.

Can you help me?? Thanks

My code JS:

```
function tryCookies(src, domain) {
    if (src == "t:s") {
        setCookie("$dtype", "", -1, domain);
        setCookie("$dtype", src, 1, domain);
    }
};

function setCookie(name, value, days, domain) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ";expires=" + date.toGMTString() + ";domain=" + domain + ";path=/";
};
```

My code HTML:

```
<object class="cd" data="WebSite" type="text/html" onload="tryCookies('t:s', 'cdiscount.com.co');"></object>
```